# How to get motherboard memory channel type using C#?

Tags: c#, motherboard

I want to get motherboard memory channel type using C#(.net), i.e. I want to get if the motherboard has single memory channel or dual memory channel.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You maybe found this information on those sites (my preference is for the first one):

- [How To Get Hardware Information (CPU ID, MainBoard Info, Hard Disk Serial, System Information , ...)](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/GetHardwareInformation.aspx)
- [Retrieving Hardware Information in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/hardware_properties_c_.aspx)
- [How To: (Almost) Everything In WMI via C# - Part 3: Hardware](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/EverythingInWmi03.aspx)